# Slot on Vuetify.js custom component

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a component  which renders a standard .
I would like to use `slots` from my component, I would like to write something like:

```
<MyComponent>
    <header>
        Titolo
    </header>
    <body>
        my component body
    </body>
</MyComponent>
```

then final component should be:

```
<v-dialog>
    <h1>
        // header slot content
    </h1>
    // body slot content
</v-dialog>
```

how can I do this? This only works with `<slot>` but not with named slot.

Answer (score 1):

To use multiple slots you can use the following syntax:

```
<MyComponent>
  <template v-slot:header>
    Titolo
  </template>

  <template v-slot:body>
    <p>my component body</p>
  </template>
</MyComponent>
```

So you can pass some HTML in the template blocks and it will render in the component.

**MyComponent.vue** has the next content:

```
<template>
    <v-dialog>
        <h1>
            <slot name="header"></slot>
        </h1>
        <slot name="body"></slot>
    </v-dialog>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define names for your slots in your custom component by using the `name` attribute available for the `<slot>` element, e.g. `<slot name="header">`. If you don't define a name for the slot, its name will just be `default`. See the Vue.js slots documentation here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html

Also, I made a simple usage example that you can check out here: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-mopsa-f47hm?file=/src/App.vue

So in your case, your custom component could look something like this:

```
<v-dialog>
  <slot name="header" />
  <slot name="body" />
</v-dialog>
```

And to use it in the parent component, you could have:

```
<MyComponent>
  <template v-slot:header>
    Titolo
  </template>

  <template v-slot:body>
    <p>my component body</p>
  </template>
</MyComponent>
```